# Rails 4 update model with subdomain and custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I can't update one user model with my custom route (without resources) and one subdomain.

My form is:

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => services_users_update_url(@user), :html => { :method => 'put', :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

while my subdomain is "services".

My routes file:

```
constraints :subdomain => "services" do  
  scope :module => "services", :as => "services" do
    match '/users/update/' => 'users#update', via: [:put]
  end
end
```

When I display my form page, the url generated in my form is:

```
http://services.website.dev:3000/8296/users/update
```

When I confirm my form, the error message is:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/8296/users/update"
```

What's wrong in my routes ?

If I try:

```
match '/users/:id' => 'users#update', via: [:put]
```

the form generate a route error too.

I also tried:

```
match '/users/update/:id' => 'users#update', via: [:put]
```

without success.

EDIT: I want to add more infos.

**My form page is located in the subdomain 'cloud' and my update action is located in the subdomain 'services'.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your url:

```
http://services.website.dev:3000/8296/users/update
                                ^^^^/^^^^/^^^^^
                                :id/users/update
```

Your routes should be:

```
constraints :subdomain => "services" do  
  scope :module => "services", :as => "services" do
    put ':id/users/update' => 'users#update', as: :services_users_update
  end
end
```

Read [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes)

Comment: If I changed for your suggestions, the form can't be displayed: undefined method `services_users_update_url'. The fact is I don't know why the user_id is in first in the url generated.

Comment: not sure about `as:` options, it should be `as: :services_users_update` or `as: :users_update`

Comment: Thanks, it works ! The correct code is `as: :users_update` without the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `resources` method to generate your route:

```
constraints subdomain: "services" do  
  scope module: "services", as: "services" do
    resources :users, only: [:update]
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not. The problem is my form is located in the subdomain 'cloud' and my update action is located in the subdomain 'services'. So what url to write in the action form if I want to use the resources path ?

Comment: try running `bundle exec rake routes | grep users`. You will see the info for the routes, with the name of the route